# Why are the positions wrong when my code is outputted?

Tags: python

```
myFile = open("task3.txt","r")
myList = myFile.readlines()
word = myList[0].split(' ')
position = [0]

for  count, i in enumerate(word):
    if word.count(i) < 2:
       position.append(count+1)
    else:
       position.append(word.index(i)+1)

position.remove(0)
print(position)
recreate= []
for count in position:
    recreate.append(word[count-1])
    print(recreate)
    with open ("test.txt","w") as file:
        file.write(" ".join(recreate))
```

Here my code is supposed to split a read file into words and positions, and use these to recreate the sentence in a new file.It does this correctly, however when i print the position they are wrong:

This is the correct positions:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 6, 7, 8]

task3.txt = one, two, three, four, five, five, four, three, two and one.

and this is what is printed: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 9, 10, 11]

test.txt = one, two, three, four, five, five, four, three, two and one.

Thank you.

Comment: Why is that the correct output? What is the input?

Comment: The positions don't seem wrong, since the positions correspond to the index of each word in the list: `two=index(8)+1=9`, `and=index(9)+1=10`, `one=index(10)+1=11`. Not sure why `6, 7, 8` would be the correct positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were expecting position to refer to some list where all the words are unique, but you never created such a list. You were instead referring to the original list where you expect duplicates.  Therefore of course the numbers jump up to skip over the existing duplicates.

I think you meant to make a new list of unique tokens, like so:

```
data = "one, two, three, four, five, five, four, three, two and one."

tokens = []
position = []
for word in data.split(' '):
    if word in tokens:
        position.append(tokens.index(word))
    else:
        position.append(len(tokens))
        tokens.append(word)

print("Here are the unique words: ")
print(tokens)

def inc(n):
    return n+1
print("Here is a list of tokens in the input, where the indexes are changed to one-based indexing:")
print(map(inc, position))

recreate= []
for token_index in position:
    recreate.append(tokens[token_index])

print("Before:" + data)
print("After :" + " ".join(recreate))
```

Output:

```
Here are the unique tokens: 
['one,', 'two,', 'three,', 'four,', 'five,', 'two', 'and', 'one.']
Here is a list of tokens in the input, where the indexes are changed to one-based indexing:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 6, 7, 8]
Before:one, two, three, four, five, five, four, three, two and one.
After :one, two, three, four, five, five, four, three, two and one.
```